# How to optimize bash script parsing multiple gzipped files with multiple patterns?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which iterates over many files: `f1.gz, f2.gz, .. fn.gz`
Each files contains millions of lines and each line could match one pattern out of set: `p1, p2, .. pn`
Depending on that, the matching line should go to a specific file. The patterns are obtained with `date` manipulations.

I wrote a couple of versions of the same but I'm not satisfied at all and I would like to ask if any better way/solution can be achieved without recurring to writing anything in compiled language.

Here's what I have:

```
for FILE in `ls f*.gz`
do

    echo "uncompressing only once per file -- $FILE: " 
    gzcat $FILE > .myfile.txt

    while IFS='' read -r LINE || [[ -n "$LINE" ]]; do

        for DATE in "$@" # I pass to my script several dates like 20201015, 20201014, etc
        do
            for i in {0..23}; 
            do
                p="DATE_PATTERNS_$DATE[$i]" # I prepared these before to avoid running "date" millions of times
                echo $LINE | awk -v pat=${!p} -F '"' '$1 ~ pat {print $2" "$4" "$6}' >> $DATE.txt
            done
        done

    done < .myfile.txt
done
```

Thanks

Comment: So many issues. Start by checking http://shellcheck.net

Comment: Will any of that make it go faster? :-) You are not helpful. Thanks for the nice link though :-)

Comment: Yes. Quoting expansions will prevent filename expansion and word splitting, which by itself will be less job for shell. How is `DATE_PATTERNS_$DATE[$i]` generated? How you prepared it? `echo $LINE` - this is just a constant pattern?

Comment: You talking about this? `ls f*.gz` ? this takes about 0.00000000000001% of the time of the script to run.. the issue is the million lines within each file which I need to iterate over.

Comment: For example. Why not `for FILE in *.gz`? Useless use of `ls`. Anyway, as a general rule - rewrite the whole `while IFS= read. do....` part in pure awk.

Comment: as far as the "for file..." yes, you are right but this really doesn't change anything in terms of speed. I don't have word splitting issues (controlled file names). as far as the echo $LINE, this is each line for the files, so it always changes. The DATE_PATTERNS_$DATE[$i] is populated before. I will add it. It's just an array to avoid launching "date" at every iteration.

Comment: let's say `$@` contains 5 dates, then you multiply that by 24x, giving us 120x copies of `echo $LINE | awk ...` (ie, scanning one line 120 times!); now multiply that by (say) 1 million rows in each of 20 `f*.gz` files ... ummmm ... 20 mil * 120 = 2.4 billion single line scans (consisting of 240 billion `echo` spawning 240 billion sub-processes to do `awk` a single line) ... yeah, we can do that ... come back in Nov ... no, Dec ... 2024 :-)

Comment: I suspect your task can be done much faster, in a robust way, with one awk command for all files. If you add some sample lines for input and output.

Comment: @markp-fuso -- yes i'm aware.. thats why i dont like it and I'm asking how to go about it in a smarter way :-)

Comment: you want to look at a solution that scans a file once (eg, have `awk` scan an entire file); next you want to look at storing the static stuff (eg, the 120x `$p` values), again, could be stored as in-memory values in `awk`; eg, store the 120x `$p` values in a file, then call (pseudo code)  `awk '{ load plist values into memory} { process myfile.txt}' plist_file mylist.txt`; then wrap this in a loop for the set of *gz files (assuming some limits on disk/cpu resources), otherwise consider Mark Sechell's comment about parallel operations

Comment: You should be able to use a single `awk` per file and use **GNU Parallel** to run as many files in parallel as you have CPU cores.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about only one awk. Made think to replace with `for { for { grep pattern file | awk {$...}`. This is not super ideal ofc, but it runs only 120 awk per file.. exponentially better :-) ..something I can run and go to sleep and find it ready tomorrow morning. Good enough. Cheers

Comment: load your 120 patterns into a file, then pass 2 files to `awk`: `awk '{ ....}' pattern_file myfile.txt`; have `awk` load the first file into an array, then as parsing the 2nd file look for the desired field 'in' the array; google search on `awk load array files FNR==NR NR==FNR` will bring up a ton of hits, like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12905373) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46039230); net result: one `awk` per file, each line scanned just once

Comment: I don't have time to  take all of that in, but I did notice `gzcat $ifile > tmp`. Look at processing like `gunzip -c $file | awk -v inputList="....."  ' ...'` where your `awk` accepts a list of dates/conditions that it will filter for and will use internal `print $0 > "/path/to/data/file.txt"` commands to generate your output. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't want to replace the code with one `awk` looping through the dates, you can start with removing the `while` (and opening the outputfile less often):

```
for FILE in f*.gz; do
   echo "uncompressing only once per file -- $FILE: " 
   gzcat $FILE > .myfile.txt

   # I pass to my script several dates like 20201015, 20201014, etc
   for DATE in "$@"; do
      for i in {0..23}; 
      do
         p="DATE_PATTERNS_$DATE[$i]" 
         awk -v pat=${!p} -F '"' '$1 ~ pat {print $2" "$4" "$6}' .myfile.txt 
      done
   done >> $DATE.txt
done
```

When you still have tried this and still want improvements, consider moving the `for DATE` and `for i` into `awk` and/or start `gzcat f*gz > .mycombinedfiles.txt` (when diskspace is no issue).

Comment: Thanks. I did part of this yesterday and the script is now workable. As a note it's actually faster to do a grep pattern | awk rather than a awk with a regex matching. I'll try the >> $DATE.txt too.